# How to get RGB values from UIColor?

Tags: ios, rgb, uicolor

I'm creating a color object using the following code.

```
curView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithHue:229 saturation:40 brightness:75 alpha:1];
```

How can I retrieve RGB values from the created color object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting rgb from UIColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816828/extracting-rgb-from-uicolor)

Comment: Just a note, the parameters passed into the method  -initWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: should all be between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700168/get-rgb-value-from-uicolor-presets/24203324#24203324

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
const CGFloat *colors = CGColorGetComponents( curView.backgroundColor.CGColor );
```

These links provide further details:

- [UIColor Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor?language=objc)
- [CGColorGetComponents reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455930-cgcolorgetcomponents)

Comment: Answer below should have been a comment. Oops.

Comment: Note: this only works for colors in the RGB space.  For example, this will not work on [UIColor whiteColor] as that is not in RGB.

Comment: I posted some sample code in this question to get this working in non-RGB contexts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700168/get-rgb-value-from-uicolor-presets

Comment: If someone finding problem on how to get values from `colors`, you can write something like, `CGFloat red = colors[0];`

Comment: `error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: 'CGColorGetComponents' has been replaced by property 'CGColor.components'`

Answer (score 121):

In iOS 5 you could use:

```
CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha =0.0;
[multipliedColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
```

Comment: This is supported only in iOS 5.0 or newer.

Comment: Be warned that this method will only succeed if the starting color is in "a compatible color space", which can vary depending on the device/OS. For example I just discovered that calling this on [UIColor darkGrayColor] will fail on an iPad 2 running iOS 7. However the same color works fine on an iPad Air running iOS 8.

Comment: @devios1 This can likely solved by first serializing the color then deserializing it using `NSKeyedArchiver`, like so: `multipliedColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: multipliedColor]];`

Answer (score 46):

**SWIFT 3 & 4**

I found that cgColor.components would not always return 4 color values, so I changed this so it gets them from a CIColor wrapper

```
extension UIColor {
    var redValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).red }
    var greenValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).green }
    var blueValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).blue }
    var alphaValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).alpha }
}
```

**SWIFT 2**

```
extension UIColor {
    var red: CGFloat{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[0] }
    var green: CGFloat{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[1] }
    var blue: CGFloat{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[2] }
    var alpha: CGFloat{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[3] }
}
```

It's not the most efficient way so I wouldn't go using this where a view will be constantly re-drawn.

Answer (score 11):

Hopefully this will be helpful

```
CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;

//Create a sample color

UIColor *redColor = [UIColor redColor];

//Call 

[redColor getRed: &red 
  green: &green
  blue: &blue 
  alpha: &alpha];
NSLog(@"red = %f. Green = %f. Blue = %f. Alpha = %f",
  red,
  green,
  blue,
  alpha);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use CIColor components
(swift 5)

```swift
let ciColor = CIColor(color: backgroundColor)
let alpha = ciColor.alpha
let red = ciColor.red
let blue = ciColor.blue
let green = ciColor.green
```

this works for non-RGB color space too

Answer (score 7):

Just made a category for this.

```
NSLog(@"%f", [UIColor blueColor].blue); // 1.000000
```

Goes something like:

```
typedef enum { R, G, B, A } UIColorComponentIndices;

@implementation UIColor (EPPZKit)

-(CGFloat)red
{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[R]; }

-(CGFloat)green
{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[G]; }

-(CGFloat)blue
{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[B]; }

-(CGFloat)alpha
{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[A]; }

@end
```

Part of [**`eppz!kit`**](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit) with more [UIColor goodies](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit/blob/master/eppz!kit/UIColor%2BEPPZKit.h).

Answer (score 5):

```
const float* colors = CGColorGetComponents( curView.backgroundColor.CGColor );
```

Thanks. I had to add the `const` at the start of the line as it was generating a warning.

Comment: did it not generate a warning for trying to implicitly cast CGFloat to float? :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 UIColor *color = [[UIColor greenColor] retain]; //line 1

//OR(You will have color variable either like line 1 or line 2)

color = curView.backgroundColor;//line 2
CGColorRef colorRef = [color CGColor];

int _countComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(colorRef);

if (_countComponents == 4) {
    const CGFloat *_components = CGColorGetComponents(colorRef);
    CGFloat red     = _components[0];
    CGFloat green = _components[1];
    CGFloat blue   = _components[2];
    CGFloat alpha = _components[3];

    NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f",red,green,blue,alpha);
}

[color release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 2.0 there is a private instance method on `UIColor` called `styleString` which returns an RGB or RGBA string representation of the color, even for colors like whiteColor outside the RGB space.

Objective-C:

```
@interface UIColor (Private)

- (NSString *)styleString;

@end

// ...

[[UIColor whiteColor] styleString]; // rgb(255,255,255)
[[UIColor redColor] styleString]; // rgb(255,0,0)
[[UIColor lightTextColor] styleString]; // rgba(255,255,255,0.600000)
```

In Swift you could use a bridging header to expose the interface.  With pure Swift, you will need to create an `@objc` protocol with the private method, and `unsafeBitCast` `UIColor` with the protocol:

```
@objc protocol  UIColorPrivate {
    func styleString() -> String
}

let white = UIColor.whiteColor()
let red = UIColor.redColor()
let lightTextColor = UIColor.lightTextColor()

let whitePrivate = unsafeBitCast(white, UIColorPrivate.self)
let redPrivate = unsafeBitCast(red, UIColorPrivate.self)
let lightTextColorPrivate = unsafeBitCast(lightTextColor, UIColorPrivate.self)

whitePrivate.styleString() // rgb(255,255,255)
redPrivate.styleString() // rgb(255,0,0)
lightTextColorPrivate.styleString() // rgba(255,255,255,0.600000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The top voted answer is outdated:

> error: :3:1: error: 'CGColorGetComponents' has been replaced by property 'CGColor.components'

Instead, use

`myUIColor.cgColor.components`

Comment: let color = myUIColor.cgColor.components



                let r = color![0]
                let g = color![1]
                let b = color![2]

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of David Rees answer:

```
extension UIColor {

    var redValue: CGFloat{
        return cgColor.components! [0]
    }

    var greenValue: CGFloat{
        return cgColor.components! [1]
    }

    var blueValue: CGFloat{
        return cgColor.components! [2]
    }

    var alphaValue: CGFloat{
        return cgColor.components! [3]
    }
}
```

Comment: This will crash the app for simple cases like `UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

Some useful macros I've made for this and other color controls:

In your case you would just use

```
getRGBA(myColor, red, green, blue, alpha);

NSLog(@"Red Value: %f", red);
NSLog(@"Blue Value: %f", green);
NSLog(@"Green Value: %f", blue);
```

---

## Macros:

```
#define rgba(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)(r))/255.0f green:((float)(g))/255.0f blue:((float)(b))/255.0f alpha:a]
#define rgb(r,g,b) rgba(r, g, b, 1.0f)

#define rgbaf(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r) green:(g) blue:(b) alpha:a]
#define rgbf(r,g,b) rgbaf(r, g, b, 1.0f)

#define rgba_fromColor(__color, __r, __g, __b, __a) \
CGFloat __r, __g, __b, __a;\
UIColor *__unpackedColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:__color]];/*Bring system colors into compatible color-space (e.g. DarkGrayColor)*/\
[__unpackedColor getRed:&__r green:&__g blue:&__b alpha:&__a];
#define getRGBA(__color, __r, __g, __b, __a) hsba_fromColor(__color, __r, __g, __b, __a)

#define getRed(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
rgba_fromColor(__color, r, g, b, a);\
return r;\
})()\
)

#define getGreen(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
rgba_fromColor(__color, r, g, b, a);\
return g;\
})()\
)

#define getBlue(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
rgba_fromColor(__color, r, g, b, a);\
return b;\
})()\
)

#define getAlpha(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
rgba_fromColor(__color, r, g, b, a);\
return a;\
})()\
)










#define hsba(h,s,b,a) [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)(h))/360.0f saturation:((float)(s))/100.0f brightness:((float)(b))/100.0f alpha:a]
#define hsb(h,s,b) hsba(h, s, b, 1.0f)

#define hsbaf(h,s,b,a) [UIColor colorWithHue:(h) saturation:(s) brightness:(b) alpha:a]
#define hsbf(h,s,b) rgbaf(h, s, b, 1.0f)

#define hsba_fromColor(__color, __h, __s, __b, __a) \
CGFloat __h, __s, __b, __a;\
UIColor *__unpackedColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:__color]];/*Bring system colors into compatible color-space (e.g. DarkGrayColor)*/\
[__unpackedColor getHue:&__h saturation:&__s brightness:&__b alpha:&__a];
#define getHSBA(__color, __h, __s, __b, __a) rgba_fromColor(__color, __h, __s, __b, __a)

#define getHue(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
hsba_fromColor(__color, h, s, b, a);\
return h;\
})()\
)

#define getSaturation(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
hsba_fromColor(__color, h, s, b, a);\
return s;\
})()\
)

#define getBrightness(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
hsba_fromColor(__color, h, s, b, a);\
return b;\
})()\
)

/*
///already defined in RGBA macros
#define getAlpha(__color)  (\
(^float (void){\
hsba_fromColor(__color, h, s, b, a);\
return a;\
})()\
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

CGColor's property [components](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/2427146-components) is what you need.

The code below

`UIColor.separator.cgColor.components`

Prints the following

`Optional([0.23529411764705882, 0.23529411764705882, 0.2627450980392157, 0.29])`

Where **the first element** of the array is **a red value**, **the second one** is **a green value**, **the third one** is **a blue value** and **the last one** is **an alpha value**. Pretty simple!

Comment: I'd say this answer is wrong, as using `CGColor` would only work if `UIColor` initialization is based on red, green and blue components. On the other hand, creating a `CIColor` from `UIColor` gives you the ability to get the RGB components even if initialized with `UIColor(hue: saturation: brightness: alpha:)` or `UIColor(white: alpha:)`,...

Comment: You're totally right. Thank you for your comment! @Andrej

Answer (score -1):

Using **[HandyUIKit](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit)** makes this **really easy**:

```
import HandyUIKit    

let color = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.3, alpha: 0.4)

// get any of the rgba values
color.rgba.red    // => 0.1
color.rgba.green  // => 0.2
color.rgba.blue   // => 0.3
color.rgba.alpha  // => 0.4
```

There is also a similar option to **get `hsba` values**:

```
let color = UIColor(hue: 0.1, saturation: 0.2, brightness: 0.3, alpha: 0.4)

// you can get any of the hsba values, too
color.hsba.hue         // => 0.1
color.hsba.saturation  // => 0.2
color.hsba.brightness  // => 0.3
color.hsba.alpha       // => 0.4
```

Simply **install it using Carthage** and you're good to go.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score -7):

set your UIColor like this

```
UIColor.FromRGB(128, 179, 255)
```

this is for Xamarin ios... but for sure there is a method like this in swift.