# How to compare a color in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to compare colors but I cannot use the `isEqual` method because I am trying to compare the color of the background of a `UICollectionViewCell`.

What is the correct way to compare colors in this situation?

```
if(cell!.layer.backgroundColor! == UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
{
    cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something but you can use cell.backgroundColor and compare it to another UIColor. I've come across this in some fast research if you're working only with CGColors, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8191171/4096655

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/970475/2303865

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `CGColorEqualToColor(_ color1: CGColor!, _ color2: CGColor!) -> Bool`.

Comment: CGColorEqualToColor is deprecated in swift3

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 or later**

`CGColorEqualToColor` is deprecated. You can now directly check them for equality:

```
let color1 = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
let color2 = UIColor.red.cgColor

print(color1 == color2)   // "true\n"
```

---

Original post

```
extension CGColor: Equatable { }
public func ==(lhs: CGColor, rhs: CGColor) -> Bool {
    return CGColorEqualToColor(lhs,rhs)
}
let color1 = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).CGColor
let color2 = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

print(color1 == color2)   // "true\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with this in a playground, I've assigned the backgroundColor property of the UICollectionViewCell with a UIColor and then created a UIColor from it's layer.backgroundColor CGColor property:

```
let blue = UIColor.blueColor()

let collectionCell = UICollectionViewCell()

collectionCell.backgroundColor = blue

let cellLayerBgrndColor = UIColor(CGColor: collectionCell.layer.backgroundColor!)

if blue == cellLayerBgrndColor {

print("equal") // Prints equal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the strings produced by calling the `.description` property like:

```
// UIColor.red.description -> "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1"
if(cell!.layer.backgroundColor!.description == UIColor.red.description)
{
    cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
}
```

But note that colorspace must also match.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3** you can simply compare the colors with `===`

```
let c1 = UIColor.red.cgColor
let c2 = UIColor.red.cgColor

if c1 === c2 {
   print('Equal')
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong except possibly for some preset colors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CGColorEqualToColor(_ color1: CGColor!, _ color2: CGColor!) -> Bool` need to use `if color1.cgColor == UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor { }` which returns `Bool`.