# colors in spritekit not matching

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift and I'm having a problem with UIColors in SpriteKit.
I'm declaring a set of colors in an enum like this:

```
enum Colors {
static let red = UIColor(red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

Then I set a SKSpriteNode, arbitrarily called element, to that colour, like:

```
element.color = Colors.red
```

If I print the values now, this will be the result:

```
print(Colors.red)
```

*UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.905882 0.298039 0.235294 1*

```
print(element.color)
```

*UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.905882 0.298039 0.235294 1*

And apparently they look the same, but if I do this:

```
print(element.color == Colors.red)
```

It's going to return *false*

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `element`?

Comment: Sorry about that I should have been more clear. element is a SKSpriteNode

Comment: When you print a `UIColor`, each component is shown to 6 decimal places. But if you pull out each value and print them with more precision, they actually differ in the 7th decimal place. So it would seem that a `UIColor` value assigned to an `SKSpriteNode` actually gets modified in a small way that makes it ever so slightly different than the original. I have no idea why.

Comment: Look at this, alternative ways are here that can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612843/how-to-compare-a-color-in-swift

Comment: Thanks, @rmaddy!

Comment: @Ehsan But we already know the two colors are different. The question really boils down to why they are different (especially since printing them confusingly makes them appear the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason: SKSpriteNode has a color with P3DisplayColorSpace as the default. You may play around:

```
  enum Colors {
    static let red = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)

}




 element.color = Colors.red
 print(Colors.red)
 print(element.color)
 print (type(of:element.color))
 print (type(of:Colors.red))
 print(Colors.red == Colors.red)
 print(     element.color ==   element.color)
 print (Colors.red == element.color)
 print(     element.color.cgColor.components![0] ==   Colors.red.cgColor.components![0])
 print(     element.color.cgColor.components![0] )
 print(    Colors.red.cgColor.components![0] )
```

Comment: By initialising with P3 everything works fine. Thank you very much!