# How do I get the value (float) for RG & B of a UIColor object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor, graphic

I have created a UIColor object and want to set the colors before drawing using CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor. In order to do that I need to extract the values of red, green and blue from the UIColor object. How do I do that?

Or is there perhaps a better way defining the color using some other kind of methods (couldn't find when I looked for it though) in which I can use the UIColor object to set the color?

Thanks in advance!

/Niklas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the RGB components in your case. Just use [CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor) instead of CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor.

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, thatUIColor.CGColor);
```

(To get the RGB components, see [*How to get RGB values from UIColor?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437113/how-to-get-rgb-values-from-uicolor).)

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. I have tried it and it fills my needs. Thanks Kenny!

Answer (score 0):

If you made a color on  a desktop, just look up the RGB values in the color picker.
Here: http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96105

Otherwise, you could just use the "default" colors, if you don'T care much about the RGB values of a color.

Like this:

```
[UIColor redColor]
```

Look at the documentation for more info.

Comment: I didn't really need to know the actual value, but it is important that it is exactly the same color that is used as the UIColor represents. I don't really know how to apply the [UIColor redColor] since it only returns a new UIColor, don't think that helps me. And the hole point is not to specify the RGB-values by hand but to reuse what is already represented by another UIColor object. Thanks anyway!