# How do I create a UIColor from RGBA?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rgb, nsattributedstring, uicolor

I want to use `NSAttributedString` in my project, but when I'm trying to set color, which isn't from the standard set (`redColor`, `blackColor`, `greenColor` etc.) `UILabel` displays these letters in white color.
Here is my line of this code.

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor colorWithRed:66
                                               green:79
                                                blue:91
                                               alpha:1]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

I tried to make color with `CIColor` from Core Image framework, but it showed the same results.
What should I change in my code to perform it in right way?

Thx for answers, guys!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Your values are incorrect, you need to divide each color value by 255.0.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:66.0f/255.0f
                green:79.0f/255.0f
                 blue:91.0f/255.0f
                alpha:1.0f];
```

The docs state:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red
                    green:(CGFloat)green
                     blue:(CGFloat)blue
                    alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

**Parameters**

**red**
The red component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

**green**
The green component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

**blue**
The blue component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

**alpha**
The opacity value of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

[Reference here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a)

Comment: It works fine, now I feel like idiot after such mistake! Thank you!

Comment: There are two new methods in UIColor that accept integer values from 0 to 255. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124535/2631081

Answer (score 29):

One of my favourite macros, no project without:

```
#define RGB(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:(float)r / 255.0 green:(float)g / 255.0 blue:(float)b / 255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define RGBA(r, g, b, a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(float)r / 255.0 green:(float)g / 255.0 blue:(float)b / 255.0 alpha:a]
```

Using like:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:RGB(66, 79, 91)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

Comment: for swift please ?

Comment: Hi @JaswanthKumar check my answer for `Swift` version.

Answer (score 5):

`UIColor` uses a range from 0 to 1.0, not integers to 255.. Try this:

```
// create color
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:66/255.0
                                 green:79/255.0
                                  blue:91/255.0
                                 alpha:1];

// use in attributed string
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:color
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try the code

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0f green:104.0/255.0f blue:159.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

like

```
Label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0f green:104.0/255.0f blue:159.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
```

UIColor's RGB components are scaled between 0 and 1, not up to 255.

Answer (score 4):

Since @Jaswanth Kumar asked, here's the `Swift` version from [LSwift](https://github.com/superarts/LSwift/blob/master/src/LFramework.swift):

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(rgb:UInt, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha)
        )
    }
}
```

Usage: `let color = UIColor(rgb: 0x112233)`