# Saving a custom RGB color with NSUserDefaults then loading it and using it to draw

Tags: colors, nsuserdefaults, rgb, save

So i am just learning xcode and i made an app learning from this website...
http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit
and there is a way to make your own custom color. What i want to do is make it so you can *save* that color with NSUserDefaults with a custom name and then the color. Then you go to one of those selectors (Picker View) and then load the color and use it.

I'm a real noob so can you explain to me how to do this in simple terms?
I really need to get this finished, so it would really help if you go back to me.

Thanks you guys,
Logan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the RGB values you have to UIColor object:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```

And save it into NSUserDefaults:  [Saving UIColor to and loading from NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults)

And then you can retrieve back the RGB values from UIColor object: [How to get RGB values from UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437113/how-to-get-rgb-values-from-uicolor)